# How to control number of APN entries in the Notification Center

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, notificationcenter

Currently I have an application that receives remote APN.  I know that you can cancel specific or all local notifications.  However, is there any way to control how many entries in the Notification Center? (Notification Center being the pull-down menu)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can control the number of notifications that can show up in Notification Center for each app, in Settings/Notifications.

As a developer, the only way you can control the number of notifications that show up in Notification Center is by controlling the number of notifications you send.

Comment: Right.  Currently, if I send one notification at a time, it will show up as "3 messages", "2 messages" and "1 message" show up in the notification center.  I would just like to display only the latest APN.  So it will only show "3 messages"; However, the badge count should still be 3.

I have read through the documentation, but there are hardly any available documentation to control the remote notifications.

Comment: Right, I'm telling you you can't do that. The only way to ensure that there's never more than one notification in the message center is to never send more than one notification (until the user opens the app, in which case you could clear all the notifications, and you'd be able to send another one again).

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.  I really hope Apple beefs up the capabilities for Notification Center in upcoming iOS then...

Comment: thanks ! we can't control apn to appear in ios notification center programmatically as android .